# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ProjectModel_

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework

Firstly I am using database first entity framework so all my model classes are auto generated 
Given the classes :

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.CustomerSites = new HashSet<CustomerSite>();
        this.Addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
    }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Company_ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string UnitNo { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public string PIC { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FK_CurrencyID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FK_PaymentTermsID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> AllowPortal { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsInvited { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> DidAccess { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsCustomer { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsSupplier { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerSite> CustomerSites { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public partial class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FK_CountryId { get; set; }
    public int FK_CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FK_AddressTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public partial class CustomerSite
{
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int FK_CustomerID { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

and my controller code to return json result for getting the customer information. I need to get customerinfo , addresses and the customersites separately.

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
var billingaddress = db.Addresses.Where(x => x.FK_CustomerId == ID && x.FK_AddressTypeId.Value == (int)AddressTypes.Billing).FirstOrDefault();
var shippingaddress = db.Addresses.Where(x => x.FK_CustomerId == ID && x.FK_AddressTypeId.Value == (int)AddressTypes.Shipping).FirstOrDefault();
List<CustomerSite> customersites = db.CustomerSites.Where(x => x.FK_CustomerID == ID).ToList();
Customer customerinfo = db.Customers.Where(x => x.CustomerId == ID && x.IsActive == true).FirstOrDefault();
return Json(new { customerinfo = customerinfo == null ? new Customer() : customerinfo, billingaddress = billingaddress == null ? new Address() { FK_AddressTypeId = (int)AddressTypes.Billing, FK_CustomerId = 0 } : billingaddress, shippingaddress = shippingaddress == null ? new Address() { FK_AddressTypeId = (int)AddressTypes.Shipping, FK_CustomerId = 0 } : shippingaddress, customersites = customersites == null ? new List<CustomerSite>() : customersites },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

So the json is returning the serializations error. I have checked few posts where they have the same situation so I have the below two lines so that the navigation properties will not be loaded.

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

when it is executing each line to get address then the customersites then the customer in the last, I was able to see that after getting the addresses the virtual property customer did not load and for customersites also the virtual property customer did not load but when I run after the customer code I was able to see that the virtual properties are automatically loaded and thus the serialization error is coming.

When I check other posts they are suggesting to use another model or retrieve only the properties required but as I am having many properties in customer I cannot follow this method.

Can someone please help me. I have some deadline for coding.

Comment: You need to use another 'view model' per the other suggestions you've read.  Serializing your entire entity object graph is not a good idea (and you'll run into problems like this one).

Comment: Thanks @Charles  Mager for the suggestion is there no other work arround for this becuase I have so many properties and in future if there are more properties to be added I am worried about that.